# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to antlr.collections.List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

If I do not do type casting to query.list(); to (List)query.list(); it gives me these errors.

[image]
 [image]

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   antlr.collections.List

on calling a method

```
category= new Category();
ArrayList data= (ArrayList) category.getCategoryInfo();
```

and method is

```
public List  getCategoryInfo(){
      Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();

      String sql = "SELECT category.id as id, category.name,c.name as parent_category FROM category join category as c on c.id=category.parent_id"; 
      SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
      query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP); 
      List data = (List) query.list();
      return data;
}
```

Please help me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: show your imports for `List` interface. Do you know what kind of `List` is returned by `query.list();` ?

Comment: Model Class Imports are as follow package 

com.jaangu.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.sql.Date;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.jaangu.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;

import antlr.collections.List;

Comment: And Service class Imports are:

package com.jaangu.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.jaangu.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.jaangu.model.Category;
import com.jaangu.model.User;

Comment: Why are you doing `import antlr.collections.List;` in your Model? Should it be `java.util.List`? Again , Do you know what kind of List is returned by query.list();?

Comment: Thanks it works for me. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Accept my answer if that solves your problem by clicking tick mark on left had side of my answer. You can accept any better answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change line,  `List data = (List) query.list();` to  `List data = query.list();` as `query.list();` always returns a `List` so no need to explicit casting.

Also , at assignment part, you again need to program on `Interface List` but you are doing on concrete class - `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList data= (ArrayList) category.getCategoryInfo();` needs to be changed to `List data= category.getCategoryInfo();`

When you program on super type interfaces, need to explicit casting is eliminated.

Note that `List` interface returned from method `getCategoryInfo()` and one written at assignment part should be the same interfaces ( either `java.util.List` OR `antlr.collections.List` , you can't mix the two ).

Figure out on your own about the kind of `List` returned by `query.list();`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've imported the wrong List class. Look at the imports of your class and replace antlr.collections.List for java.util.List.